# Google Cloud API DomainMapping using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to programmatically add a domain mapping to a service using Firebase Cloud Functions. So far was able to get the proper json field format when sending a POST request and receive a 200 success. Here is the body request/response:

**Request:**

```
{
        "apiVersion": "domains.cloudrun.com/v1", 
        "kind": "DomainMapping", 
        "metadata": {
            "annotations": {}, 
            "labels": {}, 
            "name": "subdomain.example.com", 
            "namespace": "project-id"
        }, 
        "spec": {
            "routeName": "service-name"
        }, 
        "status": {}
}
```

**Response:**

```
{ apiVersion: 'domains.cloudrun.com/v1',
  kind: 'DomainMapping',
  metadata: 
   { name: 'subdomain.example.com',
     namespace: '123456789',
     selfLink: '/apis/domains.cloudrun.com/v1/namespaces/123456789/domainmappings/subdomain.example.com',
     uid: 'eiv0wr9f-8afec-47fdsf-fdsdc-fjosf0fne78',
     resourceVersion: 'FFFJKA+F32',
     generation: 1,
     creationTimestamp: '2019-11-23T21:07:49.167253Z',
     labels: { 'cloud.googleapis.com/location': 'us-central1' },
     annotations: 
      { 'serving.knative.dev/creator': 'project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com',
        'serving.knative.dev/lastModifier': 'project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' } },
  spec: { routeName: 'service-name' },
  status: {} }"
```

When checking the status of the DomainMapping, the response message includes "Caller is not authorized to administer the domain " even though the domain is verified with google domains. Is this an IAM issue or something else? Any insight would be helpful.

Here is the full response when requesting the status of the domain mapping:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "domains.cloudrun.com/v1",
  "kind": "DomainMapping",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "subdomain.example.com",
    "namespace": "123456789",
    "selfLink": "/apis/domains.cloudrun.com/v1/namespaces/123456789/domainmappings/subdomain.example.com",
    "uid": "fdns0fs5-8fw-437f-1514c-n89fwnnav0n",
    "resourceVersion": "gn902fnfjd",
    "generation": 1,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-11-23T21:07:49.167253Z",
    "labels": {
      "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "us-central1"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "serving.knative.dev/creator": "project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "serving.knative.dev/lastModifier": "project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "routeName": "service-name"
  },
  "status": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Ready",
        "status": "False",
        "reason": "PermissionDenied",
        "message": "Caller is not authorized to administer the domain 'subdomain.example.com'. If you own 'subdomain.example.com', you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership of the domain, or any of its parent domains, via the Webmaster Central portal: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=subdomain.example.com. We reccomend verifying ownership of the largest scope you wish to use with subdomains (eg. verify 'example.com' if you wish to map 'subdomain.example.com').",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-11-23T21:07:49.719Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "CertificateProvisioned",
        "status": "False",
        "reason": "PermissionDenied",
        "message": "Certificate will not be provisioned unless the domain is made routable.",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-11-23T21:07:49.719Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "DomainRoutable",
        "status": "False",
        "reason": "PermissionDenied",
        "message": "Caller is not authorized to administer the domain 'fdsfdsfsf-gsyjtfounzbunfetzf50.a.review.activit.app'. If you own 'fdsfdsfsf-gsyjtfounzbunfetzf50.a.review.activit.app', you can obtain authorization by verifying ownership of the domain, or any of its parent domains, via the Webmaster Central portal: https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=subdomain.example.com. We reccomend verifying ownership of the largest scope you wish to use with subdomains (eg. verify 'example.com' if you wish to map 'subdomain.example.com').",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-11-23T21:07:49.719Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "Retry",
        "status": "True",
        "reason": "FailedUnknown",
        "message": "System will retry after 0:59:59 from lastTransitionTime for attempt 7.",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-11-23T23:18:06.067Z",
        "severity": "Info"
      }
    ],
    "observedGeneration": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.domainmappings#DomainMapping To make this easier to figure out, create a service in the Google Cloud Console. Then do a `GET`. You will then see how the DomainMapping object looks in JSON. Use the same format with `CREATE`. Another way is to use `gcloud run services describe <NAME> --log-http`. This will show you the HTTP request and response. You can even capture creating a service with the CLI.

Comment: @JohnHanley This is great! Very helpful to know that there is a --log-http. I was able to get the actually body that submits to Cloud Run API endpoint:  ```{
        "apiVersion": "domains.cloudrun.com/v1", 
        "kind": "DomainMapping", 
        "metadata": {
            "annotations": {}, 
            "labels": {}, 
            "name": "subdomain.example.com", 
            "namespace": "servicename"
        }, 
        "spec": {
            "routeName": "template-demo"
        }, 
        "status": {}
    };``` Unfortunately this is still returning the error.

Comment: Edit your question with the details formatted. Include the rquest, response and error message.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated the question to better reflect the issue.

Comment: Verified domains can only be used by Verified Users. Is the User ID (or Service Account Email) in the list of verified users at https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help from @JohnHandley I was able to figure out the submission format using the --log-http flag on google sdk cdi and generate a request:

```
{
        "apiVersion": "domains.cloudrun.com/v1", 
        "kind": "DomainMapping", 
        "metadata": {
            "annotations": {}, 
            "labels": {}, 
            "name": "domainMapping.example.com", 
            "namespace": "project-id"
        }, 
        "spec": {
            "routeName": "service-name"
        }, 
        "status": {}
    };
```

Make sure you also add the service account to the Verified Owners list at  google.com/webmasters/verification/home for the domain you are mapping.

Comment: Appreciate this, hit the same problem (deploying to Cloud Run using terraform, but the issues are the same). The only thing required was to add the service account's email address as a delegated domain owner in the webmaster tool.